# Changing volume with keyboard shortcuts spawns multiple volume indicators

Tags: sound, xubuntu, volume-control

A picture says a thousand words:

[image]

Pictured is the result of using the volume shortcuts on my laptop's keyboard several times to reduce the volume. This doesn't always happen. Sometimes it will spawn a few windows and then correctly modify the last one, i.e. resulting in only one popup displaying the volume as I change it.

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 with kernel `4.10.0-32-generic` on a Lenovo ThinkPad X240.

My mild guess is that it may be tied to the [KXStudio repositories](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/), which I use, but I don't think I've installed anything other than lmms and its dependencies from it. I don't recall the issue from before these but I'm not quite sure as to how it would affect, given that I only use the repositories for lmms.

Comment: If you're using KXStudios repositories, your distro is KXStudio and off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelBay KXStudio provides Debian and Ubuntu compatible repositories.

Comment: @karel Yes, they do, just like Kali. Likewise, depending on how the software is installed and the system updated it turns it into a KXStudio That's what happened here because that thing above isn't Xubuntu.

Comment: To be precise installing Kali linux tools in Ubuntu incorrectly doesn't turn Ubuntu into Kali Linux, however it does totally mess up Ubuntu and then Ubuntu reports that it's Kali Linux. So the question here is whether this issue is repairable which is not off topic.

Comment: Screenfetch and uname still report the distro as Ubuntu 16.04. I suppose KXStudio's own distro mayhaps would report as just Ubuntu as well, but I don't see why just adding the repositories would be any different from say, adding Google Chrome's repositories.